# Is there a way to sync changes from LUIS to Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Im trying to get the changes made in LUIS to the bot composer so that the reviewed utterances could are available in the composer too

Answer (score 1):

At the moment is not possible , only way you can copy the changes and paste into the composer.

Comment: Agree, you should stop using Luis portal as the source of truth. Use the .lu files in source control and publish to cognitive service from composer initially. Then to do it right don't even do that, publish from your release pipeline and during development from your local script.